# Can't connect to Postgresql with docker compose

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am developing application with spring boot.
I'm running docker-compose up but I can't connect to postgresql.

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  marketapp:
    image: marketapp
    container_name: marketapp
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

    depends_on:
      - postgresql

  postgresql:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456
      POSTGRES_DB: myapp
```

application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=123456
```

I see the following logs and errors in the terminal:
`on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc  Database system is ready to accept connections spring-market-app-postgresql-1  |  done spring-market-app-postgresql-1  | server started spring-market-app-postgresql-1  | CREATE DATABASE /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* LOG:  received fast shutdown request aborting any active transactions background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1 shutting down checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate database system is shut down server stopped`

Comment: firsth thing, in the application.properties you should use the name of the postgres container you put on the services section which is `postgresql` as it's the hostname for the postgres container, second thing is that you need to check postgresql container logs to see why it's failing to start the service. hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe share your Dockerfile so that we have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

> By default Docker Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
> container for a service joins the default network and is both
> reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
> them at a hostname identical to the container name.
> https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#link-containers

Each container can now look up the hostname `marketapp` or `postgresql` and get back the appropriate container's IP address. Your application could connect to the URL `postgres://postgresql:5432`

application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/testspring
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=123456
```

Comment: It didn't work, I got an error like this:

]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Comment: The HikariConfig error means that your main problem is solved. your application is connected to the database. I think your application config is not complete. spring.datasource.driver-class-name is missing and other properties can be added or removed depending on the version of Spring boot you are using.